# How can i set a default Router Gateway in NSX-T

Tags: vmware

For an unknown reason , either typo or fat finger my OVM deploiment of my VMware NSX Unified Appliance 3 did not take the default gateway i supplied. So as a result i can only access from a web browser on local subnet. In the Old NSX-V you could go and set the Gateway from the Webinterface but i cant find any option to do that. I found a way to set the gateway by logging in to the console and then issue a

> route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 192.168.2.1

But after a reboot that route is gone so is there a way to make this route stick ? Or is there another way ?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server/VM configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107162/discussion-on-question-by-nosoup4you-how-can-i-set-a-default-router-gateway-in-n).

Comment: Ron get a life, you don't like it if someone questions your authority so you remove comments.

Comment: The comments are still there, but the system complained that there are too many comments so I moved them to the chat where you can still argue and gripe to your heart's content, although you will simply be wasting your time because the place to argue your case is on [meta] ask I have explained multiple times, and it is in the instructions in the box above. Please open a question on [meta] to let the community decide, but you can easily get your answer on [sf], as I have repeatedly explained. SE has different sites for a reason, and each community decides what is on-topic for it.